# Accessing to a sub element via nested foreach in terraform

Tags: terraform

I have such a variable structure:

```
private-dns-zone = {
      "pdns-test-pr1" = {
        name            = "test-pr1.com"
        vnet-config-dns = "routable"
        existing        = false
        records={
          kr80lhadod04 ={
            ipv4Address="10.100.2.100"
            ttl= "600"
          }
          kr80lhadod05 ={
            ipv4Address="10.100.2.101"
            ttl= "600"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

now I would like to extract each sub element form this structure. To achieve this aim I am using this configuration:

```
resource "azurerm_private_dns_a_record" "PrivateDNSZone_A_record_routable" {
  for_each            = { for record_key, record_value in { for pdns_key, pdns_value in var.private-dns-zone : pdns_key => pdns_value if pdns_value.vnet-config-dns = "routable" && !pdns_value.existing} : record_key => record_value if record_value.records!=null }
  name                = each.value.key
  records             =each.value.ipv4Address
  zone_name           = var.private-dns-zone.records[each.value.name].name
  ttl                = each.value.ttl
  resource_group_name = var.vnet-config[var.private-dns-zone.records[each.value.name].vnet-config-dns].resource-group-name
}
```

But it seems, it is not the right one! I get the following errors:

```
records             =each.value.ipv4Address
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is object with 4 attributes
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "ipv4Address".
```

and

```
zone_name           = var.private-dns-zone.records[each.value.name].name
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.private-dns-zone is map of object with 9 elements
│ 
│ This map does not have an element with the key "records".
```

How should I adjust my configuration to make it workable?

Comment: It sounds as if you are asking about https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/flatten#flattening-nested-structures-for-for_each